# How to use regex in java to change prefix and suffix of matching substrings

Tags: java, regex

I'm wanting to (in Java) find any substrings in a string which start with say `aba` and end in say `aca`, where there is one or more non-whitespace chars between them.

For example" `blingblangabablahacablingblang` would find the substring `abablahaca`.

Then I want to replace each of those substrings, modifying the start to just `b` and the end to `ca`, but leaving the internal `blah` as it was.

For example" `blingblangabablahacablingblang` would be changed to `blingblangbblahcablingblang`.

Is there some way I can do this using String.replaceAll() ? There will be many instances within the original string to change.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
myString.replaceAll("aba(\\w*?)aca", "b$1ca") // would also match abaaca, without blah in the middle
```

or

```
myString.replaceAll("aba(\\w+?)aca", "b$1ca") // match onlu if there is a char between aba and aca
```

Comment: Thanks Mikael (and musikk). Quick, elegant, and almost perfect answer - but it gave me what I was after - just had to use \\S+? instead of \\w+? and it worked like a dream.
+1 and tick just as soon as I get enough reputation points!

Comment: @musikk Added the double slosh. That's what I get for never having compiled a java program in my life ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the Java, but the regex should simply replace 'aba(.+?)aca' with 'b$1ca'.

Comment: Thanks Thom - great suggestion too - yours and Mikael's suggestion of the group and referencing it again with $1 was what I needed.

Comment: This regex also matches whitespace between the aba and aca, and the question specifies "where there is one or more non-whitespace chars between them"

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern: `aba[a-z]*aca`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("aba[a-z]*aca");
Matcher m = p.matcher("blingblangabablahacablingblang");
while (m.find())
   System.out.println(">" + m.group() + "<");
```

Comment: This will (might) match the interesting sequence but the answer misses a solution for replacing prefix and postfix.

Comment: Also since it is greedy it matches the largest sequence starting with `abc` and ending with `aca`. This may or may not be desired by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If it is guaranteed that both `aba` and `aca` are unique within the given character sequence, then you can use the good old `String#replace` instead of regular expressions:

```
String result = original.replace("aba","b").replace("aca", "ca");
```

Comment: On top of that it must be guaranteed that they only appear in the desired order.

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with a simple if string.startsWith() and string.endsWith() and then replace the substring less then start and end and then rebuild the new string ?